# Were most of the people killed by Hamas on October 7 Israeli soldiers (at some point)?

Tags: israel, israel-hamas-war

In this [clip by Richard Medhurst](https://twitter.com/richimedhurst/status/1722809157462467056) he says,

> Israel published a list of 1,400 causalities killed on October 7th and it turns out most of them are soldiers. Their ranks are listed right along side their name: Corporal, Sergeant major, Captain, Lieutenant colonel.

In judging this claim for truth,

- Did Israel publish a list of 1,400 casualties of October 7th?
- Did most (50%+) of those have military ranks along side their names?

As he didn't claim "active duty" and it seems pointless to pretend that was the claim, we can leave that aside. He also didn't past or present, so veterans and other retired enlistees should count.

Comment: I believe Israel makes military service mandatory for adult men, much as South Korea does, so if we're including past service, this feels like a rather meaningless claim.

Comment: That there would be a published list it's not surprising. The was one well before Nov 10, although it was shorter. https://aoav.org.uk/2023/the-names-of-729-of-the-hundreds-of-civilians-killed-by-hamas-the-names-released-so-far/

Comment: @F1Krazy: service is mandatory in Israel for some women too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_Israel "Women from the Jewish majority are not exempted from the draft laws, but serve for slightly shorter terms than their male counterpart."

Comment: Other than that, I feel this Q might not be too suitable here. It seems to revolve around whom Hamas considers 'civilians' vs whom it's actually a war crime to shoot on the spot, which generally includes unarmed [potentially] combatant personnel. See e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82320/is-there-any-evidence-that-supports-hassan-nasrallahs-claim-that-idf-killed-the

Comment: If one adopts Hamas' or that Tweeter's viewpoint, this is probably objectively answerable (and moreso than other similar Q we had recently), but it probably quickly becomes one of those "yes, but..." Qs. I'm fairly torn on whether those make good Qs here. See e.g. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56272/were-70-percent-of-those-killed-in-gaza-women-and-childrenod

Comment: Israel has mandatory service for everyone once they hit the age of 18 which means every adult killed was part of the military unless they got some sort of exemption. "The State of Israel requires every Israeli citizen over the age of 18 who is Jewish, Druze or Circassian to serve in the Israel Defense Forces (although there are some notable exceptions)." https://www.idf.il/en/mini-sites/our-soldiers/s).

Comment: @F1Krazy that's incorrect. Many are not required to do military service, including the Orthodox and non-Jews.

Comment: @JoeW but still the claim isn't true because less than 1200 people have been identified so far, not everyone was Israeli, there are people who became Israeli when they were too old to serve, etc.  Also, there is a very specific list in the video that he shows and there are only ranks next to a specific number of people.  And your link isn't working.

Comment: @DavePhD I wasn't making a comment to say that the claim was true or false, just making a statement that Israel has mandatory military service which means pretty much everyone serves at some point and that status becomes meaningless.

Comment: @JoeW I don't think it's meaningless. That's Hamas's argument. If you want to concede to Hamas that's fine. I think it's fair to be skeptical about that claim and to not assume that those killed at the concert weren't innocent Orthodox Jews that had never served. We shouldn't give Hamas the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Is that a suggestion saying that it is fair game to kill almost anyone in Israel because they have mandatory military service and are ex military? I just don't think that the part about former soldiers really means anything in this case.

Comment: @JoeW Honestly, i'm split on it. These simply go down to the rules of war and what rules you're willing to accept or reject. I find that people are trained and by the military and have already shown a willingness to join as being pretty damning. But it's not clear, I'll give you that. However, to the extent this isn't clear and can be argued, we should be able to agree that these are more acceptable targets then ambulances and hospitals.

Comment: I'll put it another way... There are lots of people that are conscripted or even join a military voluntarily that would loudly dodge a subsequent draft if called upon again. I've met these people. They harbor deep regrets and guilt and see the meat grinder and empire for what it is. This is why I'm conflated, otherwise veterans are just like mothballed warships.

Comment: @EvanCarroll And my understanding is that the rules of war treat current members of the military differently then former members

Comment: @JoeW Sure, and in light of the very obvious fact which is explicit -- that the rules of war are not being followed we should question them and their moral axioms all the more. It's closer to morally justifiable, for me, to kill a vet or reservist which is a mere soldier on standby then it is to kill an infant, or the disabled.

Comment: @EvanCarroll And I disagree and would think that I am not the only one who doesn't see any thing different from killing a civilian who was never in the military and a civilian who used to be in the military.

Comment: @JoeW You don't see _anything_ different? I would go so far as to say I do think you're the only one that would make that statement. Let's say you're French soldier in WWII, and you're in the Alsace during the occupation. You have trained and retired German Nazi soldier, and a pretzel baker that happens to be German in a cafe. You can't see the moral and strategic value in killing one over the other? I'll take you for your word, but that's _really_ bizarre for me.

Comment: @EvanCarroll As someone who is former military I don't see the difference between a civilian who has never been in the military and a civilian who has been.

Comment: For those saying "if all Israelis served in the military that makes them legitimate targets" then the same applies the other way. Many people in Gaza do work for Hamas (who are the government). This includes lots of health workers. Does that make doctors legitimate targets because they work for a terrorist organization? I would not say that.

Comment: @DJClayworth Hamas is a terrorist pseudo state. And Israel is a terrorist state. No one ever said civil workers of either should be killed. I'm not sure where you got that from. When people refer to eliminating "Hamas" they don't mean schools and hospitals that are administered by the government. This is Israel's terrorist interpretation, this is what a state engaged in terror would say. It doesn't matter who pays a teacher. It does matter if the teacher is trained to fight and has taken an oath to defend the state (willing to enter as a combatant).

Answer (score 4):

The list of names shown in the OP video was [posted by Israel's official Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Israel/status/1721802362526810389)

[image: Names posted from twitter]

So it is true that Israel posted the list displayed in the video.  I haven't counted the names yet. It is difficult to tell where one name ends and another begins.

There is a more readable list with ranks [here](https://www.timesofisrael.com/authorities-name-44-soldiers-30-police-officers-killed-in-hamas-attack/):

356 soldiers and 59 police officers.  10 Shin Bet are also listed, but without rank.

However, this list includes about 37 soldiers killed after October 7th.  There is also an official [IDF website](https://www.idf.il/59780) listing the fallen soldiers.

According to the [United Nations Office for the Coordination of Humanitarian Affairs](https://reliefweb.int/report/occupied-palestinian-territory/hostilities-gaza-strip-and-israel-flash-update-34):

> The indiscriminate firing of rockets by Palestinian armed groups towards Israeli population centres has continued over the past 24 hours, with no reported fatalities. As of 9 November, the names of 1,162 of fatalities in Israel have been released, including 845 civilians and police officers. Of those whose ages have been provided, 31 are children.

> According to the Israeli authorities, 239 people are held captive in Gaza, including Israelis and foreign nationals. Media reports indicate that about 30 of the hostages are children. So far, four civilian hostages have been released by Hamas, and one female Israeli soldier was rescued by Israeli forces. Hamas has claimed that 57 of the hostages had been killed by Israeli airstrikes.

So based on information so far, depending how you consider police and Shin Bet, about 27% were soldiers and 33% were broadly security related.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable response to the claim. But 356+59+10=425. That's 37% of 1162, not 33%. Still not a majority.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I originally wrote 37% (see edits), but then I remembered to subtract the ~37 soldiers killed after October 7th.

Comment: I would include them since they're in the graphic that Israel posted which the claim is talking about. I don't think he means the October 7 attack ended at midnight. I think he means the attack that initiated on October 7.

Comment: @EvanCarroll based on the current title of the question, I don't think they should be included.  Also, the "1162" denominator doesn't seem to include them.

Answer (score -1):

## Addressing the Graphic

I ran the following graphic which seems to be used in the above Tweet through [OCR](https://www.imagetotext.info/)

[image]

I then broke it apart on what seemed to me like military titles

```
NADAV GOLDSTEIN LIMOR VAKNIN PARMOTER YUVAL BOYUM GAL SHALEV SHAI SHALEV SHANI AMIN NITZAN LIBSTEIN SUIJITH NISSANKA TAMAR GUTMAN 
STAFF SERGEANT YAM GLASS NOA FARAGE SIMON VIGDERGAUZ (DUBCHENKO) BEN ORI DOR AVITAN SIGAL ITAH EDEN NAFTALI SAPIR BILMES KARIN VERNIKOV 
STAFF SGT. YEHEZKEL (HEZI) RAZILOV AMITAY MALIHI SHARON GORDANI SHAHAR BEN NAIM ABRAHAM GILAD TIBERG OREL ABUHATZEIRA YUVAL BEN YEHUDA NATIV MAAYAN NAVE MORIAH OR SWISSA YAAKOV SOLOMON AMRAM ALON TOLEDANO SHLOMO ELIYAH ALSHICH YOCHAI BEN ZEKARYA DANIEL COHEN AVI DADON NIV RAVIV NIREL ZINI DADO TSAFIR JANA RODERMAN LORETA VILLARIN ALACRE ANGELYN AGUIRRE ANTON GORYONOV DOR HANAN SHAFIR AMIT COHEN GABRIEL YISHAY BAREL CELINE RACHEL BEN DAVID NAGAR GUY LEVI ELLA HAMUI DORIT WERTHEIM AVIV WERTHEIM YIGAL FLASH SINDI FLASH ELIYAHU ORGAD (GOLDBERG) AMAR ABU SABILA ELIYAHU (ELIKO) UZAN ARYEH UZAN YONAT OR MAOR GRAZIANI STAV GUETA EDEN BEN RUBI ASSAF MORDECHAI ADBERG YOSSEF (YOSI) WAHAB SHAHAK YOSEF MADAR LIAM GALLON NADAV YOSEF HAI TAYEB ZELTA KOSOVSKI DAN BEN HEMO AMIR TANBORA NOY AVIV ADI RIVKA MAYZEL GUY AZAR AVI SASSI YEHOSHUA HATAV MAJED IBRAHIM GABI AZULAY KARLA STELZER MENDES ITZIK DAHAN MOSHE VADI JAKE MARLOWE SOLOMON ILYAGUYEV JONATHAN KEN-DROR ALEXANDRE LOOK DAVID LISCHOV JOHN ASLANOO ROBERT SHAULOV IDAN HARMATI AVIAD AVRAHAM EDRI MOR GABAI MARK SHINDEL IDAN EDRI ANTONIO YANIV MACIAS MONTAÑO YVONNE EDEN PATRICIA RUBIO VARGAS HILI SOLOMON MOSHE SHOVA YUVAL BARON BAR ZOHAR RON WEINBERG GIDEON BABANI ROI POPPLEWELL ALINA FALHATI SHANI LOUK BANCHA DACHTUYAWAT TOU CAE LEE NANTHAWAT PINJAI MEECHAI RITTHIPHON PARINYA TAMKANG SOMKHOUN PANSA-ARD JAROON CHATDUMDEE WUTTIPAT WISETDONWAI PHITHAK THOLAENG SATTAWAT PHIAAIA JAKKAPHONG JANTHARASENA SAKSIT KHOTMEE REFAEL MEIR MASKALCHI NETANEL MASKALCHI RAFAEL FAHIMI ELI RAFAI (REFAEL) SHARON REFAI SHAHAR MANTZUR BENNY GANISH YULIYA DIDENKO LAMAI EDEN LIZ OHAYON ANULA JAYATHILAKA DANIEL KIMMENFELD PAUL VINCENT CASTELVI SEMYON AVDALIMOV TOMER SEGEV ALEXANDER SAMOILOV VICTORIA GORLOV JENNY NISENBOIM KARINA PRITIKA EDEN ABDULLAYEV RINAT ZAGDON OMRI ACHRAK ADIR MESIKA SHARONA SHMUNIS HAREL SHIRA EYLON
CORPORAL SHIREL HAIM POUR SAGIV BAYLIN BEN-ZVI MATAN ZANTI ELYAKIN NAZAROV LIBBY COHEN MAGURI SHARON HIRSCH RONI PETROVSKI TOMER STROSTA KATERINA TAVGAN GOLDMAN SHACHAR GINDI OFEK ATON AMIT LEVI BARAK DAVIDI LIOR TKACH LIOR ATUN RON SHEMER ORI TCHERNICHOVSKY ELAZAR SAMUELOV NATALIA TOMAYEV NADEJDA SPRAVCHIKOV IZHAR HAGBI DUDI SHARON ILAN AVRAHAM ROTEM RACHEL LEVI SHAMIL ABBASOV BRACHA LEVINSON ANITA LISMAN MORDECHAI BEN ARIEL BITTON INBAR SHEM TOV EFRAT KATZ LIRAZ ASSULIN MAAYAN IDAN RONEN DAICHMAN ARAN GOREN TOVA GOREN DR. HAGIT REFAELI MISHKIN MARGARITA GUSAK EVIATAR KIPNIS RAZ BOKOVZA SHACHAF KRIYF EDEN DAVID MOSHE IFTACH DAN TWEG BEN BINYAMIN COHEN DOR TOAR SHIRAZ DANIEL BRODASH BAR LIOR NAKMOLI GAYA HALIFA YONATAN ELIYAHU SHAKED HABANI MOSHE (MOSHIKO) SAIDIAN SHLOMI SIVIDIA TAL DANIELI AVIDAN TURGEMAN MASUOT YITZHAK IDO BEN ZINO AVIEL RAHAMIM NIR FORTI 
MASTER SERGEANT ZIV DADO LIOR TARSHANSKY AMIT YEHUDA BEN AVIDA AVIEL OREN ELYA ILUZ ZINAIDA BEILIN DVIR RAHAMIM GIDEON RIVLIN IDAN DOR BENAYAHU BITTON MAAYAN KALIHMAN ADI OHANA ORTAL BOBATS BEN AYUN DANIEL OHANA NISSIM LEVY DAN ZOMER SVETLANA LISOVOY YURI LISOVOY HILEL ZALMANOVICH LIVNAT LEVY LIRAZ ASULIN HAIM LIVNE ARIK ARIE HEFETZ ARIK ARIE HEFETZ YULIA CHABAN ZIV PEPE SHAPIRA YEHONATAN HAGBI ELITZUR TZURIEL HAGBI TAL BARTIK KLEIN NIV AIVAS NEVO ARAD ELDAD (ANGEL) BERGMAN ODED ABARCEL EMMA POLIAKOF RONI POLVANOV LILI ITAMARI RAM ITAMARI TOMER SHPIRER MICHAEL YOAV EINAV (HEN) BURSTEIN YOSSEF YOSSI GENIS YEHUDA BACHAR AMIT YITZHAK DAVID OFER UDI SHLOMI DAVIDOVIC HILA KLEIN MAI NAIM LIRON BARDA GIYORA DUVDEVANI ZIVA OVITZ THANAKRIT PRAKOTWONG SRITHAT KAWAO PHONGTHEP KUSARAM ANUCHA SOPHAKUN NITIKORN SAE WANG PHICHIT NAJAN APICHART GUSARAM PHIRUN THANONPHIM SAKDA SURAKHAI PONGSATORN KHUNSREE SAKSIT KHOTMEE THEERAPONG KLANGSUWAN CHAIRAT SANUSAN ARNAN PHETRKAEO SIGAL LEVY LIDOR LEVY NITZAN RAHUM BEN BINYAMIN SHIMONI LOTAN ABIR ARIK (ARIE) PERETZ MARGIT SILBERMAN YOSSI SILBERMAN BILHA EPSTEIN NIRA RONEN RIVKA BEN HORIN AMITAY BEN ZVI CAROLIN BOHL DANIEL (DAN) DARLINGTON DAVID ALBERTO SCHWARTZMAN ORLY SCHWARTZMAN PINKO IRMI SHAFIR GIDEON FAUKER SHACHAR GAL KADMAN LIOR WEIZMAN KOBI PARYANTE VITALI TROUFANOV NOY ZAFRAANI ANANDA SHAH DIPESH RAJ BISTA ASHISH CHAUDHARY NARAYAN PRASAD NEUPANE LOKENDRA SINGH DHAMI RAJAN FULARA RAJ KUMAR SWARNAKAR PRABESH BHANDARI PADAM THAPA GANESH KUMAR ROMI ELI BERNAT MODY (MORDECHAI) AMIR SHOVAL YAAKOV IDAN HERMAN CHANA KRITZMAN ILAI BARAM HEZI (YECHEZKEL) HANOM ASAF SHLESINGER HADAR HOSHEN MATIAS (HERNAN) BURSTEIN YOSEF (YOSINIO) GROSS AVNER GOREN ROEE MUNDER TAMAR GOLDENBERG MATAN ROSENBERG AVI MEGIRA CHAIM BEN-NAIM DORON MEIR MOR MEIR SHIFRA NOY SHLOMO RON SHALEV MADMONI KARIN JOURNO NOAH HERSHKOVITZ LILACH KIPNIS HAGAY EFRAT GRACIE CABRERA MILA COHEN OHAD COHEN YONA COHEN IDO EVEN ALON EVEN RINAT EVEN AVRAHAM (RAMI) KTZIR NOA ZENDER 
MASTER SERGEANT MAXIM RAZINKOV YAAKOV MORTOV BINYAMIN RAHAMIM LILIA CELLER YLENA KOSTIZIN ARIEL BILYA TATIANA SNITMAN MICHAEL OSTROVSKY IGOR KORCHER ISRAEL CHANA SOFIA POPOV VLADIMIR POPOV NOYA SHARABI LAURA FURMAN ANNA MESHAEV ROSA YIDGROV YURI YIDGROV MARIA YICHANGILOV YIFTACH YICHANGILOV SERGEI GRIDSKOL VICTORIA GRIDSKOL SHIMON HAYAT AVI HATUEL MICHAL ZARBAILOV AVI ZAKUTO HATIB ZARUK REUVEN WEIZMAN ARIEL GURI ZOYA ZEMKOV ANDREI ZEMKOV ITZIK BALTI BERTA SHIMAYEV MOSHE OHAYON ELIAD OHAYON MATAN EKSHETEIN GILAD KFIR DORIN ATIAS SHANI BEN AMI MAAYANA HERSHKOVITZ NAOR LEVY LIAV ASAYAG SEGEV SHUSHAN TAL SITON CHANA SITON YITZHAK SITON VALERY FREIDMAN OMER HERMESH SHENHAV YAAKOV SHOHAM YAAKOV LIEL CHERAFI YONATAN CHAI AZULAY SUHAIB RAZEE OFEK KIMHI ADI KAPLOUN-VITAL 
MASTER SCT. (RES.) RAN POSLUSHNI 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) ITAY YEHOSHUA 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) ARIE KRAUNIK NOYA DAN CARMELA DAN SMADAR MOR IDAN ROI IDAN LIAM SHREM HADAR PRINCE CELESTE FISHBEIN ROTEM KALDERON YAHEL SHARABI NOYA SHARABI LIAN SHARABI AYELET GODARD YEHUDIT YITZHAKI CARMEL BACHAR DANA BACHAR CHAVA BEN AMI TAL BIRA TAHEL BIRA TAIR BIRA YASMIN BIRA ORON BIRA NETA BOAZIZ MORALI GILAD BEN YEHUDA SAHAR ASHUAN MICHAL ROIMI GILI ADAR ALISIA LEVIN LINOR KEINAN MAI ITZHAKI NOREL MANZOURI ROYA MANZOURI EDEN GUEZ HANAN AMAR NITZAN GOLDENBERG ALINA WEISSBERG SHOSH (SHOSHANA) KARSENTY ADIEL TWITO IRIT KONDEROV MICHAEL VAKNIN OSHER VAKNIN SHIRAZ SHIRAN TAMAM TAIR DAVID HODAYA DAVID SHANI KUPERVASER SAVYON CHEN KIPPER OMER ZADIKEVITCH DANI ALUSH DR. LILIA GUREVICH ITAY ZAFRANI ELIYAHU YAAKOV BERNSTEIN DANIEL VADAI DAVID YAIR SHALOM NEMAN RON YEHUDAI ZE'EV HAKER ZEHAVA HAKER YUVAL SOLOMON EITAN ZIV TAMMY PELEG ZIV SENIOR 
STAFF SGT. MAJ. GOLIMA SAMZEO NOAM ELYAKIM DINA KAPSHITTER YVGENY KAPSHITTER EITAN KAPSHITTER ALIN KAPSHITTER AVSHALOM (AVSHEL) HARAN MIRA SHTAHL AVI HASDAI SLIMAN ABU MERI
SERGEANT MAJOR (RES.) TAL EILON
ADVANCED STAFF SCT. MAJ. YULLIA WEXER SAID (DAVID) MOSHE CAROL SIMAN TOV OMER SIMAN TOV ARBEL SIMAN TOV SHACHAR SIMAN TOV TAMAR KEDEM SIMAN TOV YONATAN (JONNY) SIMAN TOV SIVAN SHARHABANI TCHELET ZOHAR KESHET ZOHAR YASMIN ZOHAR YANIV ZOHAR AMIT LAHAV NETA EPSTEIN AVLOM (ALBERT) MILES IGOR LOSEV DAVID KAROL DOR RIDER SILVIA OHAYUN YUVAL BAR MAAYAN BAR MARCELLE FREULICH RAFI SVIRSKY ORIT SELA SVIRSKY RAFI MORDO PESI COHEN YOSSI APPLETON TAMAR SUCHMAN MAZAL (MAZI) BACHAR AVIAD HALEVY TZUR SAIDI OMRI RAM MERCEDES AMAR MOSHE BEN PORAT NOAM LIEL EFRAIM LEONID LOZOVSKY NAOMI DGANI ELIYAHU REICHENSTEIN NAJI ABDUSH GAL ABDUSH YOAD PEER YITZHAK LEVY SHMUEL (SHMULIK) WEISS ILAN MOSHE YAAKOV AMIT MAGNESI DORON BULDS KESHET KALFA DAVID KATZIR YAKOVI INON BILHA INON NOAM SHALOM MATAN (ELMALAM) DJ KIDO BAR TOMER AVIA GANOT ZIV HAGBI TIFERET LAPIDOT YORAM BAR SINAI REUVEN HAYNIK OREL PESSO DANIEL PELED GILA PELED ASSISTANT COMMISSIONER IZHAR PELED ZIV SHOPEN EDNA MALKAMO
SERGEANT MAJOR YANIN SIVAN SHOSHI BROSH
CORPORAL ROTEM KUTZ YIFTACH KUTZ YONATAN KUTZ LIVNAT KUTZ AVIV KUTZ JONATHAN ROM
SERGEANT MAJOR (RES.) BOAZ ABRAHAM 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) NADAV AMIKAM
SERGEANT MAJOR (RES.) OFIR MORDECHAI YARON
SERGEANT SHALEV DAGAN LIOR ATIAS ADIR TAMAM ITAY HOUSTON HADAR YOHAI AZOULAI MAAYAN MOR TAMAR SAMET LAOR ABRAMOV TOMER ELIAZ ARAVA DANIEL SHEINKERMAN ITAY BANJO GIDEON (GIDI) HIEL NOA HIEL SAN AMNON YAAKOBOV 
STAFF SGT. DOR MENGADI 
STAFF SGT. GADIF MOLOGOTA
FIRST SERGEANT BORIS DANILOV
SERGEANT DANIEL RASHED MARINA LOSEV NARKIS HAND HEN EVEN KINNERET GAT ADRIENNE NETA
MAJOR (RES.) RAM NEGBI
SERGEANT OFIR SHOSHANI LIOR ASULIN 
MASTER SCT. (RES.) RAN POSLUSHNI SHIR YARON DAN DAMARI SILVIA MARNASKY NOA GLAZBERG MOTI ELKABETZ NOY MAUDI NOAM RABIA YUVAL RABIA TSION LEVY SHIR GEORGIE GIL AVNI ORIYA RICARDO
FIRST SGT. (RES.) ABRAHAM GABRIEL KORIN
MAJ. (RES.) URI SHIMON RUSSO
SCT. ELIASAF BEN PORAT 
MASTER SGT. (RES.) SHACHAR AVIANI SGT. ADI LANDMAN
CPL. OSHER SIMCHA BARZILAI SHRAGA HASID 
MASTER SCT. (RES.) SHACHAF BERGSTEIN
FIRST SGT. IBRAHIM KHARUBA
CPL. TOMER LEIBOVITZ
SCT. YAM GOLDSTEIN ALMOC 
MASTER SERGEANT SHARON LEIBOVICH
CHIEF INSPECTOR DAN GANOT
SUPERINTENDENT AVI AMAR
CPL. ARIEL EREZ LIN DAFNI MAYA BEN DAVID RONI SHITRIT ADI MARGALIT YONATAN RICHTER
CPL. MATAN MALKA YARDEN BUSKILA ZIV FRENKEL MAPAL ADAM MOR TRABELSI HAI HAIM ZFATI RACHEL DOV MORIYA RAVIV DANIELLA DANA PATRENKO MICHAL ADMONI
CAPTAIN GUY ADMONI NOA ENGLANDER SAMMI ELGARGAWI ABED ELCARIM ELNASRASA OR ZIV EITAN SNIR DIN BAR BEN BERNSTIEN LIOR MAIMON AVIV ELIYAHU KIM DAMTI SHAY REGEV ORON BEILIN MOR COHEN
SCT. ROEE HAIM GURI 
STAFF SCT. ITAY ABRAHAM RON
SGT. OMRI PERETZ
SUPERINTENDENT MARTIN KUZMICKAS LIRAZ NISSAN MATAN LIOR MORDECHAI EYNAV ELKAYAM LEVY BEN FISHMAN 
STAFF SGT. MAJ. AARON ARTHUR MARKOVICI
SGT. BENJAMIN BLAY
SGT. MAJOR GIL AVITAL
SGT. ORI CARMI
CPL. NACHMAN DEKEL
CAPTAIN ABRAHAM HANANEL HANEDY 
MASTER SCT. AVIV BARAM
SCT. FIRST CLASS SHLOMO RASHATNIKOV
SGT. FIRST CLASS ANAR ELYAKIM SHAPIRA
SCT. FIRST CLASS DANIEL BAZGOZOV WARRANT OFFICER AVRAHAM FLISCHER
SCT. FIRST CLASS ITAMAR BEN-YEHUDA OMRI LAVI DANIELLE WALDMAN MICHAEL BEN MOSHE 
STAFF SGT. OFEK ARBIV
CAPTAIN (RES.) AMIR NAIM
LT. OMER WOLF
SGT. FIRST CLASS YISHAY SLOTKY
CPL. MATAN AVERGIL
MAJOR IDO HOBERA 
PRIVATE IDAN BARUCH
CAPT. SHILO HAR-EVEN
SCT. OR MIZRACHI
SCT. FIRST CLASS NETA BAR-AM
MAJOR SA'AR MARGOLIS
SCT. MARO ELEM
SGT. FIRST CLASS NEHORAY LEVY AMITAI
SGT. GALI ROEE SHAKOTAY
SCT. FIRST CLASS NADAV BITON
CPL. SHOHAM SHLOMO NIDAM 
STAFF SGT. DOR LAZIMI ADVANCED 
STAFF SGT. MAJ. SHARON RACHMANI DANIEL BEN SENIOR YURSLAV (SLAVA) GILLER RAM SELA BAR SHECHTER AWAD DARAWSHE YITZHAK COZIN YONATAN RAPAPORT HAGAY AVNI MATI WEISS AMIR WEISS GEULA BACHAR RAN SHEFER GIL BUYUM INBAR BUYUM HAIM ZOHAR ADI DAGAN MORDECHAI NAVEH RONI LEVY NOY SHOSH ARIK KRAUNIK EITAN HADAD SHACHAR ZEMACH SAMI KEIDAR GALIT CARBON AVI MOR SEGEV ISRAEL KISHNER AYELET ARNIN NA'AMA MOALEM SHOHAM TURGEMAN
SGT. FIRST CLASS OREL SHALOM ALON YANAI HELER HETZRONI NIR MADMON MAYA FODER
SERGEANT ADIR ESHTO BOGALE STAV BARAZANI STEPHEN MAKARCHENKO
SERGEANT SHACHAF NESANI
CORPORAL BOAZ MENACHE YOGGEV 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) NOAM SLOTKI 
STAFF SERGEANT YISHAY FITUSI
CORPORAL AMIR EYAL
SERGEANT YARIN MARI PELED
SERGEANT NOA PRAIS
CORPORAL HABIB KIEAN
SERGEANT DVIR HAIM ROSSLER
CORPORAL YAEL LEIBUSHOR
SECOND LIEUTENANT SAHAR TAL
PVT. HADAR MIRYAM COHEN 
STAFF SCT. SHOHAM BAR 
STAFF SGT. DANIEL KASAVCHUK
SERGEANT MAJOR (RES.) ILAN FIORENTINO
SERGEANT ITAY OFEK CLISKO 
PRIVATE BINYAMIN GAVRIEL YONAH 
PRIVATE LIDOR MAKIS
SCT. BARAK BEN DAVID
CPL. NATIV KUTZRO
SCT. VALENTIN (ELI) GANCIA
CPL SHIMON LUGASI
CPL. KARIN SCHWARTZMAN 
MASTER SCT. (RES.) LIRAN MONS ALMOSNINO
PVT. SHIRAT YAM AMER
SGT. NAOR SIBONI INSPECTOR KIM DUKERKER
CPL. AVIV HAJAJ
CPL. ILI BEN MUCHA
LT. IDAN BALOY
SGT. SHIMON ELROY BEN SHITRIT LIEUTENANT SHILO RAUCHBERGER
CORPORAL SHIREL MOR
SERGEANT DANIEL SHPERBER 
STAFF SERGEANT DOR YARHI 
PRIVATE MAYA VILLALOBO POLO
SERGEANT ADAM AGMON
SERGEANT FIRST CLASS ITAY YEHUDAH BAUSI 
MASTER SGT. GIL TA'ASA AVIA HETZRONI
CPL. OR AVITAL
FIRST SERGEANT YAKIR BLOCHMAN
SERGEANT AVIAD RIVLIN YOSEF SEFI GENIS GAL NAVON AMIT MANN URI ARAD ROTEM NEUMANN TAL KATZ NIV TEL TZUR
LT. SHIR EILAT OZ EZRA LI DOR LEVI
SECOND LIEUTENANT YOHAI DUKHAN MAYA BITTON ELIRAN MIZRAHI YARIN MOSHE EPHRAIM OLGA NAOMI ROMASHKIN HANANI GLAZE MAYA HAIM DANIEL GOLTMAN YAHAV WINNER ITAY BERDICHEVSKY HADAR ROSENFELD-BERDICHEVSKY
CPT. BEN BRONSTEIN 
MASTER SGT. (RES.) BEHOR SWEID
CPL. EMIL SMOYLOV
SGT. SAHAR MIDANI 
STAFF SGT. TOMER YAAKOV MIZRAHI
CPL. ITAMAR COHEN 
STAFF SGT. DVIR ZAKAI
MAJ. ILAY ZISSER
CPL. IDO BINENSTOCK
LT. ILAY ADANI
PVT. NOAM ABRAMOVITZ 
STAFF SGT. DOLEV AMOUYAL OREN ALFASI DANIEL LEVI BRUNA VALEANU BEN MENASHE MIZRAHI DAN ARIEL SMADAR MOR IDAN OMER GVERA ITAY YEHOSHUA
LT. AMIR TZUR
SGT. AMIT MOSAT 
STAFF SCT. ROI BAREKET
LT. EYAL KLEIN 
STAFF SGT YONATAN SAVITSKY
SGT. REGEV AMAR SCT. OFIR MELMAN
LT. SAHAR SAUDIN
CPL. DAVID MITTELMAN
SGT. NEHORAI SAEED
SCT. BAR ROSENSTEIN
CPL. SHALEV BARANES
MAJ. URIEL BIBI 
STAFF SGT. ELAD MICHAEL SHUSHAN
FIRST SCT. SALMAN IBN MARAI
CORPORAL NATHANE HAI LYARD
CPL. LAVI BOUCHNIK
SCT. BRANDO DAVID FLORES GARCIA
CPL TOMER NAGAR
SGT. NOAM ELIMELECH ROTENBURG
LT. RON TSARFATI 
STAFF SGT. MICHAEL BEN HAMO
LT. ORI MORDECHAI SHANY
CPL. BAR YANKELOV
SGT. AVRAHAM NERIA COHEN
CORPORAL SHAI ASHRAM 
STAFF SERGEANT MAJOR MOR SHKURI 
STAFF SERGEANT MAJOR AVSHALOM YAIR PERETZ LIEL ITACH
CAPT. SHILO HAR-EVEN
SERGEANT ROTEM DUSHI BEN BENZIYON HASID SHAY SHALOM ELIOR MUZAFI YAEL ROZMAN SOFIA BONGART ADAM ILAEV IZABELLA GANDLIN NAOR HASIDIM NAOMI BICHER 
MASTER SERGEANT ELIRAN ABARGIL
SERGEANT MAJOR YARON MORIS DAYAN
SENIOR STAFF SCT. MAJ. DAVID BEN DAYAN 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) YUVAL GABBAI
SERGEANT EVYATAR OHAYUN
MAJOR MORDECHAI SHAMIR
CORPORAL SEGEV SCHWARTZ
CORPORAL URIEL SEGAL
CORPORAL AMIR LAVI 
STAFF SERGEANT ADI TZUR
CORPORAL RAM MEIR BATITO
CHIEF SERGEANT YOSEF MALACHI GEDALIAH
CHIEF SERGEANT OMRI BALKIN SERGEANT TOMER BARAK 
STAFF SERGEANT AMIT PELED
CORPORAL SIVAN SIMCHA ASRAF 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) LIOR BEN YAAKOV
MAJOR TAL COHEN 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) TAL MAMAN
CORPORAL EREZ ARIEL
CORPORAL SHIR SHLOMO
CORPORAL OSHER SHMAIYA
SERGEANT YA'AD BEN YAAKOV
SERGEANT BINYAMIN LEV
CORPORAL SHIR BITON LIEUTENANT DEKEL SUISA 
STAFF SERGEANT DANIEL MOSHE DANINO SRG. YAKIR LEVI 
PRIVATE ILAY AZAR 
STAFF SCT. TAL LEVI
LT. EDEN NIMRI
CPL LIOR AZIZOV LIEUTENANT ALINA PRAVOSUDOVA
MAJOR ROEY CHAPELL
SERGEANT IDAN RAZ
CORPORAL ROEI PERI
CAPTAIN (RES.) DAVID HAIM MEIR
SERGEANT OR MALKA STAV KIMHI RUDY SKRZEWSKI
CHIEF INSPECTOR AVI TZIDON DUDI TURGEMAN AVI FLEISHER ITAY NAHMIAS GIL AVITAL TAL MAMAN DOR NAHUM HEN BEN-AVI DAN ASSULIN AVIAD COHEN SHLOMIT REUVEN SHISHPORTISH OFIR EREZ BERNARD COHEN IDO HUBERA 
MASTER SERGEANT (RES.) YARON VICTOR SHAHAR 
STAFF SERGEANT (RES.) OFEK ARAZI SAGI ZAK ITAY ZAK ETI ZAK SAAR MARGOLIS MENUCHA HULATI OFER RON GINA SMIATICH TOM GODO VARDA HARMATI ASSAF FEBER YUVAL GABAI AMIT GABAI DVIR KARP DROR BEHAT 
MASTER SERGEANT ELIYAHU MICHAEL HARUSH 
MASTER SERGEANT URIEL AVRAHAM OSAMA ABU ASSA MUSA ABU SABILA NIR NIKITA POPOV TAL LEVI
CHIEF INSPECTOR AVRAHAM HENKIN
PVT. YONATAN ELAZARI ALON SHAVUT YEDIDYA RAZIEL AMICHAI WIEZEN 
STAFF SGT. NAVEH ELIAZAR LAX 
STAFF SGT. TASHGAR TAKA
2ND LT. YONATAN GUTIN
LT. NITAI OMER
CPT. (RES) ROI NAGRI
SCT. YARON URI SHAY
SCT. BEN RUBENSTEIN
LT. ITAY COHEN
CPL. ILAY BAR SADEH
CPL. AMIT TZUR
MAJ. PELEG SALEM 
STAFF SGT. OREL MOSHE
CPL. ADIR TAHAR
PVT. LIOR LEVY ABED ALRAHMAN ATAF ALZIEDANA SIVAN ELKABETZ TEHILA KATABI PETRO BOSCO MOSHE RIDLER LILY KEIZMAN ROLAND SULTAN RONIT SULTAN SHLOMI MATTHIAS SHAHAR MATTHIAS
SCT. FIRST CLASS (RES.) HAYIM YESHURUN KATZMAN MEIR ELHARAR LIZ ELHARAR
CPL. AMIT GUETTA 
STAFF SCT. OR MIZRAHI
CPL. DANIT COHEN
MAJ. ARIEL BEN MOSHE
WARRANT OFFICER IDO ROSENTAL
MAJ. AMIR SKURI
FIRST SCT. AHARON FARASH
CPL. SHIRA SHOHAT 
STAFF SGT. GUY SIMCHI
CPL. ARIEL ELIYAHU 
STAFF SGT. ADIR GAURI
SERGEANT ROI WIZER ILAY NACHMAN MAOR SHALOM YOSSI TAHAR
FIRST SERGEANT DVORA AVRAHAM
SERGEANT MAJOR DENIS BELKIN
CHIEF INSPECTOR STAS SHAINKMAN
SUPERINTENDENT VADIM BLICH HALAD ALFRAHIM OSAMA ABU MADIYAM
CPL. YARON ZOHAR
1ST. LT. ROM SHLOMI
1ST. LT. ITAI MAOR
1ST. LT. TOMER SHOHAM
SGT. 1ST CLASS VITALY SKIPKAVICH
MAJ. (RES.) OMRI MICHAELI
CPL. URI LOCKER
MAJ. IDO YEHOSHUA
CPL ITAMAR AYISH 
STAFF SGT. OHAD COHEN 
STAFF SGT. ILAY GAMZO
CAPT. ARYEH SHLOMO ZIERING
CAPT. TAL GRUSHKA
PVT. OFIR DAVIDYAN
SCT. ITAI-EL MARCIANO
MAJOR AVRAHAM HOBELASHVILI
LT. COL. YONATAN TZUR
COL. ROEY YOSEF LEVY ABED ALRAHMAN EL-NASASRA LANCE
CORP. RAVIT HANA ASSIYAG 
STAFF SERGEANT ELIONA ASTAFNIKO
SERGEANT FIRST CLASS SHAI EL KNAFO
SERGEANT FIRST CLASS MICHAEL LIZMI
SERGEANT FIRST CLASS AVI BUZAGLO RUTI AKUNI TAL KEREN ADI BAHARAV HAVIK SEGAL AYELET MOLCHO SHLOMI MOLCHO OREN STERN YIGAL WACHS AMIT WACHS DALIA ABU-MADYAM MAY ZUHEIR ABU SABAAKH FATIMA ALTILAKAT MAHMOUD DIAB ALKRA'AN AMIN AKAL ALKRA'AN MALEK IBRAHIM ALKRA'AN YAZAN ZAKARIA ABU-JAMA OFIR LIBSTEIN
COL. YONATAN STEINBERG
SCT. MAJ. ARIK YEHUDAH MARZIANO
CAPTAIN (RES.) IDO EDRI
SERGEANT MAJOR AMIR FISHER
CPL. ADI GRUMAN
CAPTAIN OR YOSEF RAN
CPL. NATHANEL YOUNG
2ND LT. YOAV MELIEV 
STAFF SCT. IDO HARUSH
1ST LT. YIFTACH YABETZ 
PRIVATE NAAMA BONI 
PRIVATE NERIYA AHARON NEGRI
CPL GUY BAZAK 
STAFF SGT. YUVAL BEN-YAAKOV
SGT. EDEN ALON LEVY
CPL. DVIR LISHA 
STAFF SGT. OMRI NIV FIERSTEIN
1ST LT. OR MOSES
2ND LT. YANAI KAMINKA
SCT. AFIK ROSENTHAL
LT. COL. SAHAR MACHALOF
SGT. OR ESATU
2ND LT. ADAR BEN-SIMON 
STAFF SGT. OFIR TZIONI
CAPTAIN YOTAM BEN-BASAT
CAPTAIN ADIR ABUDI
MAJ. CHEN BUCHRIS AHARON HAIMOV MARCEL TALIA HANNAH BEN-ARTZI YEVGENY GALESKI SHALOM TZABAN DANI WOVECK MARINA ALMAGOR NURIT BERGER OR AKUNI ARYEH AKUNI 
MASTER SERGEANT ELIOR YIFRACH 
MASTER SERGEANT YAKOV SHLOMO KARSNINSKI 
STAFF SERGEANT MAJOR DROR ELTON
FIRST SERGEANT YORAI ELIYAHU COHEN
FIRST SERGEANT MALIK KARIM
FIRST SERGEANT ALEC POZNIAKOV
FIRST SERGEANT VITALY KARSI
FIRST SERGEANT ALEXEI BORODOVSKY
FIRST SERGEANT ALON BARAD
FIRST SERGEANT MAJOR BAR
SIVAN SERGEANT MAJOR YIGAL ILUZ
SERGEANT MAJOR ADIR SHLOMO
SERGEANT MAJOR RONI ABUHARON
SERGEANT MAJOR YEHUDA KEDAR
SERGEANT MAJOR ROMAN GENDEL
SERGEANT MAJOR CHEN NAHMIAS
COMMAND SERGEANT MAJOR OFFICER MEIR ABRAGIL
INSPECTOR ALEXEI SHAMKOV
INSPECTOR ANDREI POSHIVI
CHIEF INSPECTOR AMIN OHANADOV
CHIEF INSPECTOR NISSIM LUGASSI
CHIEF INSPECTOR SHLOMO MOSHE EL
SUPERINTENDENT MARTIN KOZMICHEKIS
CHIEF SUPERINTENDENT ITZHAK BAZUKA-SHVILI
CHIEF SUPERINTENDENT GE-AR DAVIDOV
```

These should be in order of the original graphic. I'm unsure of how to break the remaining lines apart based on Israeli names. And so I'll leave the rest of the quantification to the next person: if there are more than 304 names on that list without titles, it's not a majority. However there are 305 lines here. Of those 305 lines only the top line does not start with something that seems like a military title: **that means this list shared by the official Israel account, has at least 304 people affiliated with security**

Comment: FWTW, I don't see any "private (res.)" or "pvt. (res.)" in your list. So, I think they either indicate reserve status only for officers and NCOs, or they list private reservists without a title (I suspect the latter is more likely.) So this may or may not answer your Q. If the claim is just that the published list proves the majority was past-or-present military, then that's false. But if the claim is whether the majority of the dead are past-or-present military, that may no be easily concluded [either way] from the list, IMHO.

Comment: Your first line has 9 non-titled victims (Goldstein, Parmater, Boyum, Gal Shalev , Shai Shalev, Amin, Libstein, Nissanka, Gutman) https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-10-19/ty-article-magazine/israels-dead-the-names-of-those-killed-in-hamas-massacres-and-the-israel-hamas-war/0000018b-325c-d450-a3af-7b5cf0210000

Comment: A few of the titles in the list are firefighter titles, not military or police titles.  https://www.firerescue1.com/fallen-firefighters/articles/israel-fire-and-rescue-services-personnel-killed-in-hamas-terrorist-attacks-eLBgQTH0458mmTDI/

Comment: Your second line has 8 non-titled (Farage, Vigdergauz, Ori, Avitan, Itah, Naftali, Bilmes, Vernikov)

Comment: The first portion of your third line has 63 non-titled victims (Malihi, Gordani, Naim, Tiberg, Abuhatzeira, Yehuda, Nave, Swissa, Solomon, Toledano, Alshich, Zekarya, Cohen, Dadon, Raviv, Zini, Tsafir, Roderman, Alacre, Aguirre, Goryonov, Shafir,  Cohen, Barel, Nagar, Levi, Hamui, Dorit Wertheimm, Aviv Wertheim, Yigal Flash, Sindi Flash, Orgad, Sabila, Eliyahu Uzan, Aryeh Uzan, Or, Graziani, Gueta, Rubi, Adberg, Wahab, Madar, Gallon, Tayeb, Kosovski, Hemo, Tanbora, Aviv, Mayzel, Azar, Sassi, Hatav, Ibrahim, Azulay, Mendes, Dahan, Vadi, Marlowe, Ilyaguyev, Ken-Dror, Look, Lischov, Aslanoo)

Comment: Remainder of your third line has 53 for a line subtotal of 116 (Shaulov, Harmati, Edri, Gabai, Shindel, Edri, Montaño, Vargas, Solomon, Shova, Baron, Zohar, Weinberg, Babani, Popplewell, Falhati, Louk, Dachtuyawat, Lee, Pinjai, Ritthiphon, Tamkang, Pansa-ard, Chatdumdee, Wisetdonwai, Tholaeng, Phiaaia, Jantharasena,  Khotmee, Refael Maskalchi , Netanel Maskalchi, Fahimi, Eli Rafai, Sharon Refai, Mantzur, Ganish, Lamai, Ohayon, Jayathilaka, Kimmenfeld, Castelvi, Avdalimov, Segev, Samoilov, Gorlov, Nisenboim, Pritika, Abdullayev, Zagdon, Achrak, Mesika, Harel, Eylon)

Comment: @DavePhD Feel free to take my list make an answer, as I said _"These should be in order of the original graphic. **I'm unsure of how to break the remaining lines apart based on Israeli names. And so I'll leave the rest of the quantification to the next person**: if there are more than 304 names on that list without titles, it's not a majority. However there are 305 lines here. Of those 305 lines only the top line does not start with something that seems like a military title: that means this list shared by the official Israel account, has at least 304 people affiliated with security"_

Comment: @DavePhD though it sounds to me like your 116 or whatever is a far cry from 304. So I've all but already concluded that the bar of _"a majority"_ seems to be met.

Comment: @DavePhD (you can either use my data for a more specific answer or edit it, I don't care either way whatever you're comfortable with -- I just don't have anything to contribute to the Israeli name game)